# Xamarin What happens to Lazy initialized singleton after App goes to background

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I use Lazy initialization for app singleton in Xamarin.Forms (app runs on iOS):

```
public sealed class DataSingleton
{
    private static readonly Lazy<DataSingleton> lazy = new Lazy<DataSingleton>(() => new DataSingleton(), LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly); // tried withou 2nd parameter as well

    public static DataSingleton Instance
    {
        get { return lazy.Value; }
    }
    ...
}
```

And i call it in webserver which runs to provide data for Front-end which is in Angular (used web view to show Angular code)

```
var server = new WebServer(o => o
                .WithUrlPrefix($"http://localhost:{appSettings.ApiPort}")
                .WithMode(HttpListenerMode.EmbedIO))
            .WithCors()
            .WithLocalSessionManager()
            .WithWebApi("/api", m => m
                .WithController<TestController>()
                .WithController<SettingsController>()
                .WithController<ReportController>()
                .WithController<SystemController>())
            .WithModule(new ActionModule("/", HttpVerbs.Any,
                ctx => ctx.SendDataAsync(new { Message = "Error" })))
            .RunAsync();
```

In controllers is called DataSingleton to get/set data, but after app returns from background, `DataSingleton.Instance` is null.

What should I do to don't lose data of singleton, while app is in background for short time (approximately 5 minutes)

> Update - I've figured out that this problem is only in Controllers, cause when app gets back to front I can see all the data in AppDelegate `WillEnterForeground` event..

Comment: Excellent question. IMHO, The bottom line in mobile apps is that you shouldn't assume *anything* survives going to background and then returning to app. (Except for explicitly-coded background services.) You certainly shouldn't rely on anything being preserved for 5 minutes. Unfortunately that means techniques that rely on `static variables` being preserved while in background, are not reliable. General advice is to save all user data and state to persistent storage, release everything you can, then when resume, re-init everything from the saved state...

Comment: ... unless someone has a better idea, you might have to have initialization code (whenever app returns from background) that explicitly sets all Lazy statics to a new Lazy instance. Or better, does "if the Value is null, create a new Lazy". I'd love to know if anyone has further insights on this topic, and re statics in general (after return from background)!

Comment: Given your update, maybe you need to stop that WebServer when app goes into background, then run that same code again to create the server, when app returns to foreground?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve you've been right! WebServer is Disposable, so I had to manage it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that it is the webserver that is having the problem, stop it when app goes into background. Start it again when app returns (or lazy-start as needed).

Code might be something like this:

App.xaml.cs:

```
public static Webserver MyWebServer
{
    get
    {
        if (_server == null)
        {
            _server = new Webserver(...);
        }

        return _server;
    }
}
public static void StopWebServer()
{
    if (_server != null)
    {
        _server.Dispose();
        // So will be created again, on next reference to MyWebServer.
        _server = null;
    }
}
private static Webserver _server;

...

protected override void OnSleep()
{
    StopWebServer();
}
```

Usage elsewhere:

```
... App.MyWebServer ...
```

---

If you don't want to make static variable (though IMHO that is okay for App, because there is only one, and its lifetime is that of the app itself), then remove the "static"s above, usage elsewhere becomes:

```
... (Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current as App).MyWebServer ...
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, there can be race-condition.
If two (or more threads) simultaneously reads `Instance` for first time, there will be created multiple instances of `DataSingleton`. However every other read will get just one instance. It depends on your scenario, if it is ok.

```
public sealed class DataSingleton {
  private static instance;

  // will assign new DataSingleton only if "instance" is null.
  public static Instance => instance ??= new DataSingleton();
}
```

Or you can use [Interlocked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked?view=xamarinios-10.8) class ensuring, the `instance` field will not be overriden if another thread already initialized the `instance` field.

```
public sealed class DataSingleton {
  private static instance;
  public static Instance {
    get {
      var result = instance;

      // early exit if singleton is already initialized
      if (result is not null) return result;

      var created = new DataSingleton();
      // thread-safe way how to assign "created" into "instance" only if "instance" refers to null. othervise no assignment will be made
      var original = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref instance, null, created);

      // some other thread already initialized singleton
      if (original is not null) return original;

      // return newly created instance
      return result;
    }
  }
}
```

Or you can use `lock` to ensure, just one instance is created.

```
public sealed class DataSingleton {
  private static instance;
  public static Instance {
    get {
      var result = instance;

      // early exit if singleton is already initialized
      if (result is not null) return result;

      lock(typeof(DataSingleton)) {
        result = instance;

        // double check, if instance was not initialized by another thread
        if (result is not null) return result;
    
        return instance = new DataSingleton();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is an issue? Lazy doc explicitly states that by default, it is thread safe. The sample code at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?view=net-6.0 demonstrates threads that each call `lazy.Value` - same as being done in this question.

Comment: ... and in any case, this almost certainly has nothing to do with the issue of returning from background, which occurs on the app's main thread - so multi-threading is not a factor.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I understand that the object in static field is lost and the static property returns null. This is solution for it. If I understand wrong, I'll delete the answer of course.

Comment: Ahh, I see your point. You are showing an alternative to using `Lazy`. In which case you do need to deal with thread safety. Anyway, the first sentence of your answer does not apply to the question's original code, as `Lazy` does that for you. (According to the docs - I have not personally verified.)

Comment: Slightly simpler code: `if (instance == null) lock(typeof(DataSingleton)) {` `// Double check inside the lock to avoid race condition.` `if (instance == null) instance = new DataSingleton(); }` `return instance;`

Comment: This aproach did not help..